# Add Queries to Team Favourites in the Process Template - TFS2012

Tags: agile-processes, tfs-process-template

We are using the Agile Process Template of TFS2012 (slightly modified) and I want to add queries to Team Favourites in the template so that they will be automatically added on creation of a new team project. We want to see the same queries for every team project.

I have modified the template so that instead of the 3 Iterations being created (Iteration 1, Iteration 2 & Iteration 3), it just creates a single Iteration named 'Current'. I have then updated all of my queries to point to the 'Current' iteration instead of Iteration 1. Now I need to add these queries to Team Favourites so that they display on the web screens automatically.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that queries are relative to one team project, and one only.

Displaying queries on the Team Favorites section can be achieved by following these steps:

> 1. From the team home page, click the link for View work items
> 2. In the work item page left pane, find the query that you want to show
> 3. Right click on the query name
> 4. Select 'Add to team favorites'"

Also see the following article, the section on Shared Queries:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286695.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This I can already do but I wondered if I can perform these actions automatically in the Process Template? I can create queries and add those to the Process Template so I was hoping I could add these queries to Team Favourites? Cheers